# Can I pass a parameter to a Windows Service Application Delphi

Tags: delphi, service

I have been installing and uninstalling my Delphi Windows Service with below mentioned commands, but now I want to pass my own parameter which does not show in ParamStr

`MySrvc.exe /Install /Silent`

`MySrvc.exe /UnInstall /Silent`

Below is the code I am using just to check if I get the params. Only ParamStr(0) gets save in the text file ie: the Exe Name.

```
procedure TVPS_Srvc.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
var
...
begin
  bJustStarted:=True ;
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if bJustStarted then
      begin
        sl:=TStringlist.create ;
        sl.Add(paramStr(0)+' '+paramStr(1)+' '+paramStr(2)+' '+paramStr(3)) ;
        sl.SaveToFile('C:\ABC\params.txt');
        Freeandnil(sl) ;
      end;
      ....
end;
```

Comment: As far as I know you need to use service control manager to pass additional parameters when starting your service like mentioned in [How to start a service with certain start parameters on Windows](https://serverfault.com/a/143409/578367)

Comment: That worked, guess was expecting the parameters to show up while Installing the Service and not when Starting the Service. The Start happens Automatically upon installation.

Answer (score 1):

Command line parameters are accessible via `ParamStr()`. But, the only way to make command line parameters available in the `TService.OnExecute` event is to manually modify the Registry to edit the command line that is used to execute the service. Otherwise, you have to put the desired commands in the SCM when starting the service. Those parameters are accessible via the `TService.Param[]` property instead of `ParamStr()`.